# Maven - transitive dependencies with different versions

Tags: maven, version, transitive-dependency

- Let's assume my application needs `foo.jar` and `bar.jar`
- `foo.jar` needs version 1.0 of `c.jar`
- `bar.jar` needs version 2.0 of `c.jar`

How does Maven resolve this conflict? Which version of `c.jar` will be used?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on the order of declaration in your effective POM.  If `foo.jar` shows up first you will get version 1.0 of `c.jar`.  If on the other hand `bar.jar` is declared first it will be version 2.0 of `c.jar`.

Relevant [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> ...two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency
>   tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but
>   since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the
>   first declaration wins

Comment: This is a criminal design flaw of Maven

Comment: It's not a design flaw, this is the default behavior. You can use `<exclusions>` to explicitly handle such cases